# how rotate and move the color legenda

Tags: python, folium

Below is part of my code. The most important is: how add color_map to folium. I have question to legenda (on picture). How can I rotate the legend to vertical and move to down right corner?

```
import folium
import branca.colormap as cm
color_mapa=cm.linear.YlOrRd_09.scale(1,10)
color_mapa=color_mapa.to_step(index=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])
m=folium.Map(location=[52,20],zoom_start=7)
color_mapa.add_to(m)
color_mapa.caption='Colors'
color_mapa.add_to(m)
m.save('D:\KMiT\Python\mapy\mapy_test.html')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folium does not have this functionality.

However, you can use leafmap with the folium backend (`leafmap.foliumap`). Since the backend is folium all the folium objects can be applied to the leafmap map.

Link for your reading:

https://leafmap.org/notebooks/62_folium_colorbar/

Comment: Thnk, it's good idea, but is it possible to add my own colors instead of cmap ? For example params = {'width': 0.3,'height': 4, 'vmin': 0, 'vmax': 6000, 'cmap': 'gnuplot2', 'label': Elevation (m)',    'orientation': 'vertical',    'transparent': False,}, but I would like change on colors['darkblue','red','orange'] - I can't find this option. It's very important because I define colors color_mapa=cm.linear.YlOrRd_09.scale(1,10)
color_mapa=color_mapa.to_step(index=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]) and use it's in my data so I need the same colors on legend and on map.

Comment: You should theoretically be able to write any discrete or linear colormap you like and have it show up. Use `m.add_colormap(palette = colors, discrete = True)`. Write colors as a list with the exact colors you want. Example usage:


`m = leafmap.Map()`

`colors = ['ffffcc', 'e9261f', '8d0026', 'db141e']`

`m.add_colormap(palette=colors, discrete=True, vmin=10, vmax=100)`

Play around with the other parameters, but from a cursory look it should be possible.